# Where does the SAML NotOnOrAfter Condition Originate?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, okta, shibboleth-sp

I have a client where the `NotOnOrAfter` condition in the SAML response is always 5 minutes after login.  The IdP is Okta and the SP is Shibboleth SP 3.  I am not seeing anything on the Shibboleth side that adds this condition.  I'm being told Okta isn't sending this, but I'm skeptical.

I even tried adding Ignore PolicyRules for it, but we still have a 5 minute timeout.

`<PolicyRule type="Ignore">saml2:NotOnOrAfter</PolicyRule>`

Does the IdP or SP add that timeout?  Where can it be changed?

Here is the excerpt from the SAML response:

````
<saml2:Subject xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">userid</saml2:NameID>
    <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_bb4020da3209979ab2c018077ec29894"
                                       NotOnOrAfter="2023-02-07T21:25:38.782Z"
                                       Recipient=https://sitename.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST/>
    </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
</saml2:Subject>
<saml2:Conditions xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                  NotBefore="2023-02-07T21:15:38.782Z"
                  NotOnOrAfter="2023-02-07T21:25:38.782Z">
    <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
        <saml2:Audience>https://sitename.com/shibboleth</saml2:Audience>
    </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
</saml2:Conditions>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but it should correspond to your authentication policy (sign-on) session lifetime applied during user authentication.

Comment: The local authentication session lifetime generally is much longer than the SAML assertion lifetime.